# PHP move_uploaded_file() issue

Tags: php, linux

I have the PHP script (testupload.php):

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('log_errors',1);
    ini_set('error_log','/root/work/inputs/log_file');

    $target_path = "/work/inputs";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['frag3']['name']);
    echo "Received File: " . $_FILES['frag3']['name'] . " and moving it to " .  $target_path . "<br>";

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['frag3']['name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['frag3']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

And the HTML file to call it:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <body>
            <form action = "http://localhost:8081/testupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <span>Value : </span><input type="text" name="Value" value="Hello world"/><br />
                <span>Fragment File : </span><input type="file" name="frag3" /><br /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

However, I continually recieve the response:
**`There was an error uploading the file, please try again!`**

So it's clear that `move_uploaded_file()` is not correctly functioning. Plus, it doesn't actually move the file. However, I can't seem to diagnose the issue.

My first thought was that the directory was not writable. But my permissions for the folder are `drwxrwxrwx` (as determined by `ls -l`)

Also, the line:
ini_set('error_log','/root/work/inputs/log_file');

doesn't seem to write a log file to that location.

Has anyone had any experience with this? How can I diagnose whats going on here?

I am almost at a loss here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using OpenSUSE 11.2, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.3.

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['frag3']['tmp_name'], $target_path)`

Comment: The value for $_FILES['frag3']['tmp_name'] appears to be blank. Why would this be? There is a value for $_FILES['frag3']['name'] though (which is why I - incorrectly - used that). Any thoughts?

Comment: You'd better first check `$_FILES['frag3']['error']`, and the error code definition is here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I did just that! It was a file size limit. But I changed everything to tmp_name too, so that helped. Guess I had two issues! Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to check:

- Ensure that your file upload and post limits are not reached by editing `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `.htaccess` or `php.ini` file. If you have error reporting on, you should see an error when they're reached. See this: http://drupal.org/node/97193
- Check for file upload error codes. See the documentation for these: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
- Ensure that your `memory_limit` has not been reached. Again, with error logging enabled, you should receive an error message about this. http://drupal.org/node/207036
- Check PHP's common pitfalls documentation and make sure there's nothing there that helps: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

If none of this helps, enable error reporting and post what you receive so we can tailor our answers better to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

the php stores the file in server with temporary name 
which you can get by

`$_FILES['frag3']['tmp_name']` and not by `$_FILES['frag3']['name']`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['frag3']['tmp_name'], $target_path)`, as the files aren't actually stored by the name they're uploaded with (though you can, of course, rename them by setting their target path to such).